# Looking for a solution to extend the time of PHP Session login script

Tags: php, session

I'm looking for a solution me and my freelancer scripter cannot fix haha!

After 25 minutes of inactivity my reservation script log-out automatically and gives me a header already send error on line 722. I need to login again to proceed. I cannot refresh the page but must go manually to index.php to log-in.

I searched the stack overflow forum for solutions and I found an answer to change the settings in the php.ini. I did this but stil it doesn't work (php info shows now the correct value of 31536000s on local and master). I also changed the PHP session time in the reervation script without any results..

Other thing I tried I found on the forum is a .htaccess file but also doesn't work.

What can I try more?

**PHP.ini**

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 31536000
session.cookie_lifetime = 31536000
```

**Variables.php**

```
if (session_id() === '') {
    session_set_cookie_params(172800, APP_BASE_PATH, $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], false, true);
    session_start();
}

if (!headers_sent()) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), session_id(), time() + 172800, $params['path'], $params['domain'], $params['secure'], $params['httponly']);
}
```

**Line 722 of my script**

```
function verify_logged_in() {
if( ! isset( $_SESSION['logged_in'] ) || $_SESSION['logged_in'] !== true ) {
    unset( $_SESSION['logged_in'] );
    unset( $_SESSION['last_used'] );
    unset( $_SESSION['user_id'] );
    unset( $_SESSION['user_type'] );
    unset( $_SESSION['user_name'] );
    unset( $_SESSION['full_name'] );
    unset( $_SESSION['email'] );
    unset( $_SESSION['token'] );
    session_write_close();
    $_SESSION[ 'message' ] = 'U dient opnieuw in te loggen.';
    header( 'Location: index.php' );
    exit();
}
else {
    $_SESSION['last_used'] = date( DATE_TIME_FORMAT );
}
```

```
<?php
require_once 'functions.php'; 
$lang = "en";
if (isset($_SESSION['language'])) {
    $lang = $_SESSION['language'];
}
require_once "lang.".$lang.".php";
verify_logged_in();
verify_user_level(['Editor', 'Moderator']);
```

Comment: `<?php 
    require_once 'functions.php';
    $lang = "en";
    if(isset($_SESSION['language'])){ 
     $lang = $_SESSION['language']; 
    }
    require_once("lang.".$lang.".php");
    verify_logged_in();
    verify_user_level( [ 'Editor', 'Moderator' ] );`

Comment: You need to look for any output, either whitespace or HTML or `echo/print` before this function is called. It could be in your translation file or in the functions.php

Comment: So the header already send error ok. but why after 25 minutes ?

Comment: After you set the php.ini settings to what you wanted, was the web server restarted?

Comment: Yes.. the master settings is even set by webhosting manager.

Comment: Are you saving sessions in the database? If so, it could be a database timeout.

Comment: The default timeout of a session is 1440 seconds. You can check what the manager did with `echo ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime");`.

Comment: @chriswhite Only stores last active in database

Comment: @kiko software the gc.maxlifetime is 31536000

Comment: Just to be sure: You did check that with the code I gave? Sorry, but some people just make assumptions and stick to it without ever questioning it.

Comment: Php info shows the correct value :) thats the same

Comment: Yes, `phpinfo()` shows it too. Well 1440 seconds is 24 minutes, which is very close to 25 minutes... and as far as I know that's the only setting close to that time. I still haven't figured out why you overwrite the session cookie. It probably has something to do with wanting to keeping it alive, but it is strange. I would let the PHP session manage its own cookie.

Comment: So I removed the header function and the "header already send error" is gone.. but still after 25 minutes the scripts log-out.